# Проблема с cookie

Tags: jquery, cookie

Данный код отвечает за сворачивание/разворачивание блока

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/jquery/cookie/1.0/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function showhide(n){
      if(n == 3){
       $('#std'+n).slideToggle('slow');
       if($("#openlink").html() == "<img src=\"/style/default/img/otdz.png\" alt=\"\" title=\"Свернуть\"/>"){
        $("#openlink").html("<img src=\"/style/default/img/otdz.png\" alt=\"\" title=\"Развернуть\"/>");
        $.cookie("filter_open", "0");
       }else{
        $("#openlink").html("<img src=\"/style/default/img/otdz.png\" alt=\"close\" title=\"Свернуть\"/>");
        $.cookie("filter_open", "1");
       }
      }
     }
    </script>
```

Но немного не так работает. По умолчанию у меня блок свернут. Когда его разворачиваю, потом обратно сворачиваю, обновляю страницу он у меня все равно развернут пока не почищу cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Выполнять `.slideToggle()` стоит только в случае несоответствия установленной куки состоянию блока. Я бы добавил проверку перед тем, как переключать, примерно так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showhide(n){
        if(n == 3) {
            if( 
                ( $('#std'+n).is(':visible') && $.cookie('filter_open') == "0")
                ||
                ( $('#std'+n).is(':hidden')  && $.cookie('filter_open') == "1")
            ) $('#std'+n).slideToggle('slow');
            if( $("#openlink").html() == "<img src=\"/style/default/img/otdz.png\" alt=\"\" title=\"Свернуть\"/>") {
                $("#openlink").html("<img src=\"/style/default/img/otdz.png\" alt=\"\" title=\"Развернуть\"/>");
                $.cookie("filter_open", "0");
            } else {
                $("#openlink").html("<img src=\"/style/default/img/otdz.png\" alt=\"close\" title=\"Свернуть\"/>");
                $.cookie("filter_open", "1");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Вообще не вполне понятна логика: что за `n`, и когда вызывается приведённая ф-я.

Comment: Вообще перестало все работать с этим кодом.

Применение:


<a href="javascript://" onclick="showhide(3)" id="openlink"><img src="/style/'.$setup['skin'].'/img/otdz.png" alt=""/></a>

if(isset($_COOKIE['filter_open']) && $_COOKIE['filter_open'] == 1)
 {
 echo '<div id="std3">';
код
echo '</div>';
}

Comment: Т.е. если куки нет, или она не "1", то ваш php вообще не выводит этот блок! : ) Что ж Вы хотели. Выводите его в любом случае.
Приведённый в ответе JS я не проверял и не отлаживал - он просто демонстрирует идею. Тут не принято готовые решения за Вас писать.

Comment: Выводит. Просто не дописал.

Comment: Если кука равняется нулю, то фильтр свернут. Что-то не выходит сделать так чтобы равнялась нулю.